# show cities from state id in database PHP

Tags: php, state, show, city

I'm trying to make a php website

in the register page I user must choose the state (select input) then the cities input will appear after he chose the state.

this is my work but not work, I need correct or other solution to fix it please :

```
>     $states = get_states();
>     
>     if($states == NULL)
>       die('Problem');
>     
>     $scount = count($states);
>     if($scount == 0)
>       die('No States');
```

//******************

> ```
>  <?php
>     if(isset($_POST['state']))
>   {
>       for($i=0; $i < $scount; $i++)
>       {
>           $state = $states[$i];
>           if($_POST['state'] = $state->name)
>           {
>               $regions = get_regions_by_state($state->id);
>
>               if($regions == NULL)
>                   die('Problem');
>
>                 $rcount = count($regions);
>
>                 if($rcount == 0)
>                   die('No regions');
>
>               for ($i=0; $i < $rcount; $i++)
>               {
>                   $region = $region[$i];
>                   echo "<option value=\"$region->id\">$region->name</option>";        
>               }
>
>           }
>         }         
>   }
>   ?>
> ```

Comment: Could you post a `var_dump` of the `$_POST` variable and the body of the `get_regions_by_state` function ?

Comment: What error do you get? Basic debugging please.. :\

Comment: if not a typo that you made while posting this question, you are trying to assign, not comparing, change the second if statement as `$_POST['state'] == $state->name`.

Comment: it work now, but how I can load the page in itself. isset is not work?